# Linear Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve next problem:

Let $M_{n}$ be the set of matrices of order $n\times n$ end $S=\left\{A\in M_{n}; x'=Ax  \mbox{ is hyperbolic} \right\}$ Show that $S$ is open and dense in $M_{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, hyperbolicity means than none of the eigenvalues of $A$ have zero real part.

A non-hyperbolic matrix can be made hyperbolic by adding a small multiple of identity. Thus, hyperbolicity is dense.

If $A_n\to A$ and for each $n$ there is $y_n\in\mathbb R$ such that $\det (A-iy_n I)=0$, then the sequence $(y_n)$ is bounded. Choose a subsequence $y_{n_k}\to y$ and conclude with $\det(A-iyI)=0$. Thus, non-hyperbolic matrices form a closed set.